# Пересылка на другой адрес

Tags: javascript, jquery

При выходе из фрейма использую такую страницу переадресации, которая выводит из фрейма в одно окно и пересылает на нужную мне страницу. В Хроме все это работает без проблем, в в IE не работает.
В чем может быть проблема?

```
<html><head>                                                              
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  

var form=$("<form/>").attr({
    method: "post",
    action: "http://kmr/",
    target: "_top"
});
form.append($("<input/>").attr({name:"field1",value:0}));

$("body").append(form);
form.submit();

</script>                                                      
</head>
<body> 
</body></html>
```

Comment: если _blank поставить вместо _top?

Comment: не помогло. да и зачем мне открывать в новом окне.